# ES6 modules' path resolution failure

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to use the new ES6 features in Chrome 60 (by enabling [Experimental Web Platform](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5365692190687232)). This is the structure of my project:

```
myproject
├── src
|   ├── mymodule.js
|   ├── dep1.js
|   ├── dep2.js
|   ├── dep3.js
├── pages
    ├── example
        ├── example1.html
```

This is my page `example1.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>E6 6 experiments</title>
    <script type="module" src="../../src/mymodule.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I set up [Http-Server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server):

```
http-server /Users/myuser/myproject
```

So that I have a server running and serving stuff (in order to avoid CORS issues related to using the `file:///` protocol). When I run Chrome and type in the address bar: `localhost://pages/example/example1.html`, I get this error:

```
[Error] GET http://localhost:8080/src/dep1 
[Error] GET http://localhost:8080/src/dep2 
[Error] GET http://localhost:8080/src/dep3
```

### Dependencies not loaded

Developer Tools window shows that `mymodule.js` is correctly loaded, but its dependencies not, the path is not correct. File `mymodule.js` has these 3 lines at the beginning:

```
import * as dep1 from "./dep1";
import * as dep2 from "./dep2";
import * as dep3 from "./dep3";
```

Remember that `dep1.js`, `dep2.js` and `dep3.js` are in the same location as `mymodule.js`.

I think that `mymodule.js` is loading resources fine, otherwise if it depends on where the server is having the root this becomes tricky. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hm... Haven't tried this myself but I wonder if the imports are actually relative to the document (as in the html) for some reason? What happens if you change your imports to `import * as dep1 from "/src/dep1"`?

Comment: Nope, jk. The server 404 errors say otherwise.

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen Same thing, same exact errors

Comment: Are you able to get to those files directly from your browser?

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen I can get them, the browser correctly fetches the javascript files, so they are available from an HTTP server perspective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the log, the relative path is resolved correctly, the folder is the expected one. The problem is that your files are called `dep1.js` not `dep1` (etc). Add the file extension:

```
import * as dep1 from "./dep1.js";
import * as dep2 from "./dep2.js";
import * as dep3 from "./dep3.js";
```

Alternatively you can configure your server to resolve these automatically.

Comment: @Andry Where does the spec say that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @Andry That's not [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#resolve-a-module-specifier). Also it only says "*the module identified by "my-module", **often** "my-module.js"*". Maybe they should make it clear that how "identified by" works depends on the module loader - and native modules don't (yet?) automatically guess an extension.

Comment: My bad I actually wanted to link another article, the actual specification, but by having a second look I just realized that it is as you said! Thank you very much for your help