# Compile modules with TypeScript for the browser with bare ES modules

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm trying to compile TypeScript code to JavaScript such that I can use it in my `index.html` as follows

```
<script type="module">
    import('./dist/base.js').then(module => {
        const instance = new module.MyClass();
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Note the `type="module"`! So, if `base.js` would look like this

```
export MyClass {}
```

it works like a charm. However, my case is a but more complex and I have 2 problems

1. it is all in TypeScript and it doesn't compile to the right format
2. I also import a library from 'node_modules'

**Problem 1)**: When I run `tsc` it produces the following output

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
class MyClass {}
exports.default = MyClass;
```

Here is my best attempt of `tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNEXT", 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"], 
    "outDir": "./dist",
     "strict": true,   
     "moduleResolution": "node"
}
```

But I've tried many more `target`s and `module`s

**Problem 2)**: Ignoring problem 1) consider the following

```
    import { magic } from 'magic';

    export MyClass {
         doMagic() { return magic() }
    }
```

It compiles to

```
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    const magic_1 = require("magic");
    class MyClass {
        doMagic() { magic_1() }
    }

    exports.default = MyClass
```

The browser can not resolve `require("magic")`. I think `tsc` should have inlined that script, I don't know, but this will not work.

So, maybe I'm doing something wrong with one or more of the `tsc` options in `tsconfig.json` or do I need other tooling (babel/webpack) as well. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at [How to make TypeScript output valid ES6 module import statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45932526/215552)

Comment: I get the impression that the post you're referrening to is about the file extensions of imported files (also very interesting I must say!)