# How to not specify file type as .js in a .ts file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My goal is to import .ts file as it is instead of specifying the file type as `.js` e.g `import {acccessRights} from "utils/accessRights"`.

My expected result: I can import a method from other file without specifying the file type.

My actual result: It throws error `GET http://127.0.0.1:5501/build/lights/switchLights net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`.

**Temporary solution**: specify the file type as .js e.g `import { switchLights } from "lights/switchLights.js"`. However, the jest will break because it does not find the `.js` file.

part of index.html

```
<body>
  <script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

part of app.ts

```
import { User } from "./utils/accessRights";
import { switchLights } from "./lights/switchLights";
```

utils/accessRights.ts

```
export interface User {
  role: string;
}

export function userIsAdmin(user: User): boolean {
  return user.role === "admin";
}
```

lights/switchLights.ts

```
import {User, userIsAdmin} from "../utils/accessRights";

let lightsCondition: boolean = false;

function switchLightsRender() {
  document.getElementById("lightsCondition").innerHTML = lightsCondition ? "ON" : "OFF";;
  document.getElementById("lightsButton").innerHTML = `Lights ${!lightsCondition ? "ON" : "OFF"}`;
}

export function switchLights(user: User) {
  if (!userIsAdmin(user)) return false;
  lightsCondition = !lightsCondition;
  switchLightsRender();
  return true;
}
```

**These are the jest files for the unit tests.**

test/utils/accessRights.test.ts

```
import {userIsAdmin, User} from "../../src/utils/accessRights";

export let userTest: User = { role: "admin" }

test('user is admin', () => {
  expect(userIsAdmin(userTest)).toBe(true);
})
```

test/lights/switchLights.ts

```
import {userTest} from "../utils/accessRights.test";
import {switchLights} from "../../src/lights/switchLights";

test("lights switched ON/OFF", () => {
  let lightsConditionRef = document.createElement("span");
  lightsConditionRef.setAttribute("id","lightsCondition");
  document.body.appendChild(lightsConditionRef);

  let lightsButtonRef = document.createElement("button")
  lightsButtonRef.setAttribute("id","lightsButton");
  document.body.appendChild(lightsButtonRef);
  
  expect(switchLights(userTest)).toBe(true);
})
```

**This is one of the transpiled .ts file to a .js file**

The issue is that the auto generated code does not specify the file type in the import

My expected result:

```
import { userIsAdmin } from "../utils/accessRights.js";
```

My actual result:

```
import { userIsAdmin } from "../utils/accessRights";
```

This is the auto generated file.

build/lights/switchLight.js

```
import { userIsAdmin } from "../utils/accessRights";
var lightsCondition = false;
function switchLightsRender() {
    var lightsConditionRef = document.getElementById("lightsCondition");
    if (lightsConditionRef !== null)
        lightsConditionRef.innerHTML = lightsCondition ? "ON" : "OFF";
    ;
    var lightsButtonRef = document.getElementById("lightsButton");
    if (lightsButtonRef !== null)
        lightsButtonRef.innerHTML = "Lights " + (!lightsCondition ? "ON" : "OFF");
}
export function switchLights(user) {
    if (!userIsAdmin(user))
        return false;
    lightsCondition = !lightsCondition;
    switchLightsRender();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a transpiler/compiler to convert the typescript to JS?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes. I use `"module": "es2015"` in the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Sorry, I meant do you use a tool like, parcel, webpack, etc? The reason I ask is because you can't import a typescript module into a native JS module (native meaning not transpiled) and expect it to work

Comment: "However, the jest will break because it does not find the .js file." Could you please include this file, and the thrown error in the question?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, I use `Live Server` extension from the VS Code to run the `index.html`, and I also run `tsc --watch` to transpile it automatically.

Comment: @Olian04 Feel free to check it again, I have updated the post.

Comment: can you not just allowJs in your tsconfig.json.

Comment: @SteveTomlin I add `"allowJs": true` it still throws the same error. I checked the transpiled `.js` file, it turns out the import does not contain .js / it's get transpiled as it is `import { switchLights } from "./lights/switchLights";` while it should be `import { switchLights from "./lights/switchLights.js";`. It's the **transpiler bug**, not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Where exactly does "importing switchLights.js" help, in what file?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. No that's definitely not the way to go. I'll investigate.

Comment: @Elias the `import { switchLights } from "./lights/switchLights.js"` should be in the transpiled `.js` file from `.ts` file. I will update the post to clarify what I mean.

Comment: The auto-generated code would not specify the type in the import. It's an all or nothing kind of thing so if you transpile code all your sources would then be .js so they'd only include .js files and therefore the transpiler should not need to include the extension.

Comment: @apokryfos Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45932526/how-to-make-typescript-output-valid-es6-module-import-statements). I think it should if you specify the correct module type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your issue: [How to make TypeScript output valid ES6 module import statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45932526/how-to-make-typescript-output-valid-es6-module-import-statements)

### Solution:

Use a bundler. I'd suggest using [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) for now, mostly because it doesn't require any setup.

If you need to configure a lot of things and have edge cases, I would recommend using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

#### Installing parcel

1. `npm i -D parcel`
2. Actually change the import in your HTML file form `app.js` to `app.ts` (or whatever your file is called).
3. Add an npm script to develop:

```json
"scripts": {
  "serve": "parcel index.html"
},
```

4. run `npm run serve`

This will host a server for you (URL in the terminal) and recompile if you change anything.

[Parcel Documentation(Getting Started)](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html)

Comment: What about using `tsc` the typescript compiler? That's what the OP is already using

Comment: @evolutionxbox Have you looked at the link I put at the top of my answer? As far as I understood it, that's not possible.

Comment: @Elias I use `parcel` with `tsc` as well. It works. I have no idea why. I still use `.js` in the script tag `<script src="build/app.js"></script>` and use `tsc --watch` to compile.

Comment: @kidfrom You don't have to use `tsc --watch` to compile. `parcel` will do that for you

Comment: @Elias am I using it the wrong way?as you said it's not possible.

Comment: @kidfrom No... I think the issue is that the people developing the standard have not yet decided.

Comment: @kidfrom Please use the `ts` path e.g. `src/app.js` or whatever. Otherwise it will use the js from the build. I mean I assume it works if you run `tsc --watch` but that would just compile it twice. Once from `ts` to `js` and once from modules to whatever (I actually don't know lol).

Comment: @Elias thanks, this is a new knowledge for me. I usually use library e.g React or Angular, so I never had this problem. I will use parcel and remove the tsc compiler.