# Module not found without '.js' in the end of import filepath

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation

I think solution is not hard, I've just something obvious.

I have a simple project on TS. Without any modules, just TS for compilation. TS-files compiling into js-files at dist folder, and than they all connect into app.js(ts), which connect at index.html(structure of project you can see on photo).

When files compilated, there aren't any errors, but browser can't find imported files, until I edit this:

```
import { ProjectList } from "./components/project-list";
```

to this:

```
import { ProjectList } from "./components/project-list.js";
```

in compiled js files.

Why it do not working without '.js'!?

At index.js I specify script type="module".
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's how it's _supposed_ to work with ES modules, see e.g. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35589#issuecomment-564644320

Comment: If you don't want the `.js` then rename `validation.js` into `index.js` and put it inside a folder named `validation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45934667/4518630

Just use `import { ProjectList } from "./components/project-list.js";` in your TypeScript code and it should work