# How to reference local file in ESM module when writing in TS?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a Lambda function written in NodeJS that i'm shifting to ESM.

I'm importing a local file, `import { fetchUrl } from './lib/fetch';` but as the main file is ESM, I believe it needs to be `import { fetchUrl } from './lib/fetch.js';`.

But I'm writing everything in TS,  including the file `fetch.ts` (which gets compiled to `fetch.js`.

How can I reference the JS file in the main TS file before the JS file exists? Will it just "know" that the file will exist when its eventually compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45934667/4518630

Just use `import { ProjectList } from "./components/project-list.js";` in your TypeScript code and it should work

Comment: Why do I need to have `.js` on the end of local files, but not modules loaded from `node_modules`?

Comment: Check the link I've included, it's explained there

Comment: That's the way TS is working and it's explained in the included link and using this way you don't need to update generated .js files. Is the solution I've suggested works? If so, please accept the answer